# Setting AUParameter's value from Host App

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

## The Problem

I am trying to get the new `AUParameterTree` and `AUParameter`'s mechanism working in my Audio Unit V3 test project.  The problem is that when I gain a reference to it from the Host App and change its value, the Audio Unit extension's parameter doesn't appear to change.

Here is my approach.

I'm using the new Audio Unit V3 API.  I've created an `AUParameter` in my `AUAudioUnit`'s `initWithComponentDescription`:

## Creating the Parameter

```
  AUParameter *param1 = [AUParameterTree createParameterWithIdentifier:@"frequency"
                                                                    name:@"Frequency"
                                                                 address:frequencyAddress
                                                                     min:500
                                                                     max:5000
                                                                    unit:kAudioUnitParameterUnit_Hertz
                                                                unitName:nil
                                                                   flags:0
                                                            valueStrings:nil
                                                     dependentParameters:nil];
```

Set a default value..

```
param1.value = 0.5;
```

---

some of the arguments to the Parameter constructor come from...

## Some State

I have defined the address as a global constants:

```
const AudioUnitParameterID frequencyAddress = 0;
```

And a local variable for an `AUValue`:

```
AUValue frequency = 1;
```

*Keep in mind at this point I'm just following the three example projects that use Audio Unit V3 on the entire internet.  I find it difficult to piece together how this entire AU parameter dance should go only from reading the docs.*

---

## Rendering with the parameter

now when it comes to using the `AUValue` associated with the `AUParameter` "param1",  (I assume thats how it works?)..

I am then capturing this `AUValue` ( the local variable which I'm unclear on how it is associated with the actual `AUParameter` ) .. in my Audio Unit rendering block:

```
- (AUInternalRenderBlock)internalRenderBlock {

    AUValue * param1Capture = &frequency;

    return ^AUAudioUnitStatus(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *timestamp, AVAudioFrameCount frameCount, NSInteger outputBusNumber, AudioBufferList *outputData, const AURenderEvent *realtimeEventListHead, AURenderPullInputBlock pullInputBlock) {

        // use parameter value
        someValue = *param1Capture;
        // more dsp stuff..
```

---

## Controlling Parameter from Host App

This is where the problem arises.

I declare a local reference to an `AUParameter`:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    AudioEngine *_audioEngine;
    AUParameter * _param1;
}
```

and when my Audio Engine class instantiates my `AUAudioUnit` it passes it to me:

```
 [_audioEngine setupAUWithComponentDescription:desc andCompletion:^(AUAudioUnit * unit){

        _param1 = [unit.parameterTree valueForKey:@"frequency"];        
 }];
```

## no effect?

Now when I say:

`[_param1 setValue: 1000];`

The captured `AUValue` in my rendering block remains the same!

I've either overlooked a bug, a mindless type (I may have introduced a type in this write up of my problem so keep that in mind), or I have fundamentally misunderstood this mechanism.

If I need to provide more context for this problem I can easily push the project to Github.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to have nothing to do with Core Audio and everything to do with a basic language level mistake.

`frequency` was declared at a file level scope like this:

```
AUValue frequency = 1;
@implementation MyAudioUnit
@end
```

My understanding is that  `frequency` is now bound to file scope and not instance scope.  Therefore repeated setting of it on different instances was simply overwriting the previous value.  Hence, the last assignment was the frequency which would be rendered.